# BroadCast Intent WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION not calling and hence not getting list of peers

Tags: android, android-wifi

Hey I am making an android app based on training samples from developer.android.com Here is my MainActivity Code :

```
    package com.example.hellowifi;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.net.wifi.WpsInfo;
    import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
    import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
    import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
    import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pInfo;
    import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
    import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
private WifiP2pManager mManager = null;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel = null;
private BroadcastReceiver mReciever;
private ListView mListView;
public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";

// TXT RECORD properties
public static final String TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE = "available";
public static final String SERVICE_INSTANCE = "_wifidemotest";
public static final String SERVICE_REG_TYPE = "_presence._tcp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    mReciever = new WiFiBroadCastReciever(mManager, mChannel, this);
    startRegistration();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mReciever = new WiFiBroadCastReciever(mManager, mChannel, this);
    registerReceiver(mReciever, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReciever);
}

public void OnDiscoverButtonClicked(View view) {
    mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Discovery Process Succeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("changed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Discovery Process Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private static List peers = new ArrayList();/*
private ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,peers);*/

static WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
        peers.clear();
        peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());
    }
};

private void startRegistration() {
    //  Create a string map containing information about your service.
    Map record = new HashMap();
    record.put(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE, "visible");

    // Service information.  Pass it an instance name, service type
    // _protocol._transportlayer , and the map containing
    // information other devices will want once they connect to this one.
    WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo serviceInfo =
            WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance("_test", "_presence._tcp", record);

    // Add the local service, sending the service info, network channel,
    // and listener that will be used to indicate success or failure of
    // the request.
    mManager.addLocalService(mChannel, serviceInfo, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added Local Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed to add a service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and my Broadcastreciever class is this :

```
package com.example.hellowifi;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WiFiBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private MainActivity activity;
private WifiP2pManager mManager=null;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel=null;
PeerListListener myPeerListListener = null;

public WiFiBroadCastReciever(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                   Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.mManager = manager;
    this.mChannel = channel;
    this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action=intent.getAction();        

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

        int state=intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED==state)
            Log.d("WiFiBroadCastReciever", "WiFi enabled");
        else
            Log.d("WiFiBroadCastReciever", "WiFi disabled");
    }
    else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "in intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (mManager != null) {
            mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, myPeerListListener);                
        }
    }
    else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
        if (mManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // We are connected with the other device, request connection
            // info to find group owner IP
            /*mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, connectionListener);*/
        }

    }
    else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

    }
}

final HashMap<String, String> buddies = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

}

I am getting successful calls to Broadcasting Intents WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION,WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION,WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION but not to WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION
when I am making tethering and portable hotspot to other device and trying to discovering on my device.

Note that: WiFi is enabled and I am also getting Toast of Discovery successful. After that WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION intent is not calling.
I tried searching on each and every thread.
Please try to help me someone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run discoverPeers() on other devices as well.
Now you will receive the WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION intent

Comment: i am doing the same but still `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` is not broadcasted.. @Jithu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. Please check below scenario how I have fixed the issue.

First I have implemented the same code in server and client android device with minor changes. I have placed a button in server app to invoke the discoverPeers() method. At the same time my client app is running and connected to the same WI-FI network. Then it triggers the WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION event from broadcast in server app. There I have got the list of nearby peers.